# Odoo api.model from Odoo documentation, what is `model.env`?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to define a method `@api.model`:

```py
@api.model
def test(param1, param2):
    print model.env['product.template'].search([("company_id", "=", param1), ("warehouse_id", "=", param2), ])
```

Question is, [official documentation](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/environment.html#environment) states that you can use `model.env` but when I try to do it I get:

```
NameError: global name 'model' is not defined
```

which is the  right `import` to use to get `model` available?

Answer (score 2):

What is meant by `model` is that you need a model object (empty recordset) to be able to access `env`. In the new API, `self` will be a recordset, so you can access the environment via `self.env`:

```py
@api.model
def test(self, param1, param2):
    print self.env['product.template'].search([("company_id", "=", param1), ("warehouse_id", "=", param2), ])
```

Note that the method should be defined on a [model class](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#creating-models) (in your snippet, the `test` method signature is missing `self` parameter).

On a related note, the link you have provided is not from the official documentation and is outdated - it was written in the period of initial migration from the old API to the new API between OpenERP 7.0 and Odoo 8.0, so it is not the best source. I would suggest to refer to the offical documentation available on [Odoo.com](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.api.model).

Comment: And how can I get an empty recordset for a given model? I am invoking a custom `@api.model` method from XMLRPC, hence, I have no `self` as there is no specific recordset such as in `read` method.